# Last 30 days of data

Tags: oracle, date, where-clause

I cant figure out a where clause to get me the last 30 days of data from a table

```
Select DATE_ADDED
From INFORMENT.PRODUCT_OFFER_PURCHASE
WHERE ??????-30
```

I have tried WHERE NFORMENT.PRODUCT_OFFER_PURCHASE.DATE_ADDED > sysdate-30
and that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: My confidence in you is shaken by the misspelling of the schema name and the complete lack of any reason for why this does not do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

```
date_added >= trunc(sysdate)-30

date_added >= sysdate-30

date_added >= add_month(sysdate,-1)

date_added >= add_month(trunc(sysdate),-1)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think its just type mistake

```
Select DATE_ADDED
From INFORMENT.PRODUCT_OFFER_PURCHASE
WHERE 
INFORMENT.PRODUCT_OFFER_PURCHASE.DATE_ADDED > sysdate-30
```